# Lettuce behavior when redis db is down

Tags: redis, database-connection, connection-pooling, spring-data-redis, lettuce

We are using lettuce in our redis based api (spring boot). Do we need to implement circuit breaker in our api in case redis database goes down OR lettuce connection pool (using the default connection pool) handles database down scenario itself? The idea is, we should not be consuming connections from the connection pool if database is down.
tnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lettuce does not have Circuit Breaker capability built in. A circuit breaker is usually an application concern or at best a capability to be slapped on top via a wrapper library like [Resilience4j](https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs/circuitbreaker)

If you do not have a wrapper library around Lettuce and if you do not want to litter your codebase with circuit breaker composition APIs, you could let Lettuce connection exceptions bubble up and handle these centrally to open the circuit breaker. A simple exception handler that verifies [StatefulConnection.isOpen()](https://lettuce.io/core/release/api/io/lettuce/core/api/StatefulConnection.html#isOpen--) before opening the circuit breaker may be all that is required.

Comment: Thanks Ashwin for clarifying that lettuce does not have circuit breaker capability. I will be implementing resilience4j then. However, I could not understand central exception handler logic. Can you please explain a bit.

Comment: @Sukh There are multiple ways to do this but the right choice depends on your context. THe simplest is Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler which works on a per thread basis and every thread needs to be wired with one handler instance for it to work. OTOH, if you are utilizing an executor service, then you could extend it and add your override for afterExecute to handle these exceptions at the executor level. Refer: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#afterExecute(java.lang.Runnable,java.lang.Throwable)

Comment: if I get an exception in case db is down I can handle that exception. But if more requests would come then they still be using the connection from the connection pool and soon my connection pool would be exhausted. Resilience4j can help me not call the method responsible for db query in case db is down hence saving connections from connection pool. I do not think this can be covered by exception handling. Thoughts?

Comment: By handling the exception I was answering techniques to centrally place the code meant to open the circuit breaker and stop further calls.